# Как нарисовать/вывести текст для значений осей координат в OpenGl? C++

Tags: c++, opengl

Вот программа, для вывода самих осей, нужно только их подписать:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "C:\\opengl\\glut32.lib")
#include "C:\\opengl\\glut.h"

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glLineWidth(3);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    glVertex2d(100,100);
    glVertex2d(0,250);
    glVertex2d(100,0);
    glVertex2d(200,250);
    glEnd();

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2d(-20,-20);
    glVertex2d(-20,300);
    glVertex2d(-20,-20);
    glVertex2d(300,-20);
    for(int i=-20; i<300;i+=20)
    {
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2d(i,-15);
        glVertex2d(i,-25);
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2d(-25,i);
        glVertex2d(-15,i);
    }
    glEnd();
    SwapBuffers(wglGetCurrentDC());
    glFlush();
}

    void reshape(int w, int h)
    {
        glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
          glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
          glLoadIdentity();
          glOrtho(-100.0,400.0,-100.0,400.0,1.0,-1.0);
    }

int _tmain(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("...");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Здесь](http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/nehe14.htm) можно найти неплохой урок по выводу текста средствами `OpenGL`. Реализовывать glPrint из урока Вам, возможно, и не надо, хватит просто вызова функции `void glCallList(GLuint list)` -- посмотрите только функцию `BuildFont`. В конце статьи есть ссылки на проекты для разных сред разработки.